# aLIGO potential signals mimicking GWs not considered in the team publications?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, ligo

[EDITED to accommodate info from the comments]

Among the local atmospheric electromagnetic potential sources of a signal capable of mimicking the waveform of a GW not sufficiently considered by LIGO and  are sferics and radio bursts in relation with lightning and with terrestrial gamma-ray flashes associated to thunderstorms.
As discussed in the comments in the presence of some charge in the interferometer it is plausible(see calculations in the comments below) for a radio wave in the 35-70 Hz range of frequency to produce a few oscillations and with a magnetic field just under what woud be detected by the magnetometers. Once this oscillatory force produce displacement on the mirrors it is also a possibility considered in the GW optomechanics literature, by the optical spring property that the detuned signal recycled cavity that forms between the signal recycling mirror and the other mirrors, that the laser radiation pressure anti-damping effect leads to a few more cycles with freq going up towards the optical cavity resonance before it is quickly damped. Precisely this signal recycling-optical spring property is exploited by the AdvancedLigo interferometer to get close to or even beat the standard quantum limit(SQL) of detectibility and enhance the sensitivity in the presence of an actual GW in these low frequencies(under 300 Hz is where amplitude sensitivity is maximized) associated to binaries spiraling and merging, but it is also known to be capable of producing parametric instabilities.(see for instance chapters 3, 11 and 12 of "Advanced interferometers and the search for gravitational waves" edited by Bassan or consult the arxiv for papers by Meers, Chen and Buonnano)

So given all this it is hard not to wonder why LIGO and other scientific groups independent of LIGO haven't apparently considered this kind of potential electromagnetic radiation sources of confusion, if only to critically scrutinize the interpretation of a single event put forth by a single team like it should always be done in science.

ADDED june 18th 2017: After more than a year and over 2000 citations finally one team makes the actual effort of going critically through the published data from LIGO and publish their conclusions: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04191 . Basically they find that when doing the analysis template-free it can be seen that the noise during the GW "signal"(with the analysis done either with the signal substracted or not given the weakness of the putative GW amplitude) is also lagged 6.9 ms between detectors, when it should be stochastic. And that "noise" could perfectly accomodate a signal of lightning related events of terrestrial origin(that could go perfectly unnoticed by the magnetometer as shown in the comments below), but certainly as a whole not the shape of a GW signal.

Comment: Fermi doesn't actually *monitor* TGF per se, these events simply trigger [the GBM](http://gammaray.nsstc.nasa.gov/gbm/) on-board. That said, I'd need to see a paper showing that  a TGF (a) could produce a similar waveform and (b) appeared that runs along LA & WA (or vice versa) where the two LIGOs are located.

Comment: How does a flash of light impinge on a mirror inside a concrete tunnel or differentially change the path length? Also how does your idea produce nearly coincident signals in detectors separated by 1000s of km?

Comment: As commented before this is not in the visible range of EM radiation, it is gamma-rays with much much more energy per photon. As for the nearly coincident signals, these are EM wave, travel at c. Depending on the angle of incidence they will have different tranfer of momentum to the reflecting surface, producing slightly different amplitudes of oscillation.

Comment: @kyle a) I would also like to see such paper, if only to discard it based on solid physics. The actual weight of my question is to wonder why this hasn't been considered by LIGO, while they have papers on something like Schumann resonances for instance. It would be great if someone related to the Ligo collaboration clarified this.

Comment: Why would LIGO consider it, if there are no papers suggesting similar signal? These anti-gravitational waves posts I'm seeing posted here are just ridiculous...

Comment: So according to you even if the physics is possible, if there are no papers written we should just forget about it right? Do you realize that until last september there was not an instrument on earth with the sensitivity of the aLIGO interferometers? It was LIGO responsibility to consider all possibilities as they claimed they did.

Comment: BTW, I'm not anti-gravitational waves at all, they are predicted by GR. I'm basically against scientists announcements that later turn into a mock of science.

Comment: Yes, they claimed responsibility for consider all other reasonable claims. There is no expectation that they check for every hair-brained scheme internet crackpots come up with.

Comment: And my comment was to point out that if there is no paper trail that such a theory exists, how can *anyone* be expected to test against it?

Comment: What theory? Electrodynamics? Earth science?

Comment: The theory that a TGF can produce a similar waveform as merging black holes, as stated in point (a) I made in the very first comment (and that you have subsequently been defending).

Comment: If you think that it is impossible and can even begin to reason it physically why don't you write an answer instead of acting like a troublemaker in the comments section? I might even accept it if you show you not only are in the insulting remarks bussiness  but actually know some physics .

Comment: I will write up an answer if you can give the source that shows that, *Under the right circumstances of angle and intensity of the flash beam impulse a vibration of the mirrors on both LIGO sites could be produced of the form seen in GW150914* otherwise, this is just more crackpottery not with anyone's time.

Comment: aLIGO controls for this sort of thing by having electromagnetic, mechanical, and thermal detectors on site. The sort of effect you describe (an electromagnetic wave mimicking a BBH inspiral; I haven't read the details of your specific theory) is of course possible, but it would set off the electromagnetic detectors. And they didn't go off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radiation pressure from a ~50 Hz (freq of the aLIGO wiggle) radio wave with an amplitude of 1pT (a typical Schumann wave) or 10pT (which is E=cB=3 mV/m) for a less frequent Q-burst (associated with Sprites) is very very small.  Also, it would push the 40kg mirror mass in one direction only. If it arrived as an impulse, the mirror would swing at its pendulum freq of < 1 Hz and not make a ~50 Hz chirp back and forth waveform.

However, you may be looking in the correct place for a non-gravitational effect.  It turns out aLIGO's end mirrors may be charged!!

If there was a ~50 Hz radio wave with a chirp pattern, it might be able to explain what aLIGO saw.  At a recent aLIGO talk, I asked the speaker about the charge on the end mirrors.  He said a charge may be there and was an active topic of investigation within aLIGO.  For now we will have to estimate it.  The position of the 40 kg x .34 m diam mirror is controlled by pushing against another mass hanging from the same pendulum stage.  This adjustment is needed to precisely send the laser beam back down the 4 km to the splitter mirror.  This pusher plate is 5 mm away, has concentric electrodes on it, and is divided into quadrants.  As I understand from an aLIGO paper, up to +-280 volts (and up to an additional 500 volt offset) may be placed on these electrodes. If the average voltage on these electrodes is not zero, then the other plate of the capacitor (the mirror) charges up. The capacitance between the two plates is 160 pf.  If (wild guess) the average voltage were 100 v, then the mirror would have q=CV= 16 nC of charge on it.

For a driving freq of 50 Hz, the mirror (< 1 Hz pendulum freq) behaves as a free mass.  So the amplitude of its motion for a 10pT Q-burst is:

$$
x=\frac{qE}{m (2\pi \nu)^2}=\frac{(16*10^{-9}coul)(10^{-11}Tesla)(3*10^8m/sec) }{(40kg)(2\pi 50 sec^{-1})^2}=1.2*10^{-17}meters
$$
$$
strain=\frac{1.2*10^{-17}meters}{4000meters}=3*10^{-21}
$$
The 50 Hz radio wave would also be attenuated by ~1/3 by passing thru a 1 cm aluminum vacuum chamber wall.  The aLIGO signal at both interferometers had an amplitude of $.5*10^{-21}$ so a Q-burst size signal, happening in the ionosphere between the two interferometers, is large enough given our assumption of 16 nC on the mirror.

A 10 pT amplitude signal would not have been vetoed by the aLIGO magnetometers.  A LIGO paper said the magnetometers had a noise of 4pT/sqrt(Hz).  Integrating this over the bandwidth 35-350 Hz that aLIGO filtered its strain signal, the magnetometer threshold for detecting a glitch was probably greater than 71 pT.

However, in googling the literature, I have found no atmospheric effect waveform that looks like the aLIGO chirp (increases in freq and amplitude as time progresses).  The Q-burst mentioned above is a spike with some decaying oscillations of about the correct freq and does not look like the aLIGO chirp.  Though aLIGO's detection doesn't look like a Q-burst, the above calculation shows (if 16 nC on the mirror is correct) that an electromagnetic wave could make the observed strain and escape the magnetometer's glitch veto.  Perhaps LIGO has discovered some previously unknown, small, and infrequent electromagnetic atmospheric phenomena?

Maybe someone from within LIGO is on Physics Stack and can comment/ add info.

What the aLIGO signal is will become clearer as they see more events.  Very exciting, and I too hope it is a gravitational wave for the window this would open on the universe!

**Addendum 1:** Calculation of the strain caused by a "~100 Hz laser spring oscillator" receiving a .005 sec (=1/2 period) impulse of EM radiation perpendicular to the mirror face and completely absorbed by the mirror.  The 100 pT EM wave is probably just below what the magnetometer will veto as a glitch.

The momentum pmax transferred to the mirror oscillator is

$$
pmax=\frac{1}{c\mu_0} (E\times B)*Area=\frac{(3*10^8m/sec)(10^{-10}Tesla)^2(\pi (.17m)^2)(.005 sec)}{(3*10^8m/sec)(4\pi 10^{-7})}=3.6*10^{-18} kg-m/sec
$$

After 1/4 of a period the mirror will have p=0 at its max amplitude of xmax

$$
xmax=\frac{pmax}{m(2\pi \nu)}=\frac{3.6*10^{-18} kg-m/sec}{(40kg)(2\pi100sec^{-1})}=1.4*10^{-22}m
$$
$$
strain=\frac{1.4*10^{-22}m}{4000m}=3.6*10^{-26}
$$
which is much less than the $10^{-21}$ peak strain aLIGO saw.

**Addendum 2:** Now consider if Terrestrial Gamma Flashes(TGFs) of ~1 MeV gamma rays might give a LIGO mirror enough impulse.  Assume the 40 kg mirror is absorbing relativistic particles like photons so $p=\frac{E}{c}$.  Calculate how much energy must absorbed by the "100 Hz laser spring osc" to account for the strain amplitude seen.

$$
E=c*pmax=c*m(2\pi \nu)xmax=(3*10^8 m/sec)(2\pi*100Hz)(10^{-21}*4000m)=3*10^{-5}joules
$$
Convert this to MeV and divide by the area of the mirror
$$
Flux=(\frac{3*10^{-5}joules}{1.6*10^{-13}joule/Mev})(\frac{1}{\pi (17cm)^2})=2*10^5Mev/cm^2
$$
The Fermi papers say the TGF events are <1/4 msec (so ~delta function impulse to excite our 10 msec period osc) but do not report the total energy deposited in the GBM BGO.  What they do say is that the largest TGF events they have seen have ~300 gammas in the ~300 cm2 area of their BGO detectors, the energy spectrum falls ~$E^{-2}$, and ~40 MeV is the largest energy gamma they have seen in ~3000 events in 4 years of data.  So, we can calculate a big overestimate of the MeV/cm2 they have seen in their rarest event:
$$
Flux_{GBMmax}=\frac{300*40Mev}{300cm^2}=40Mev/cm^2
$$
This falls 4-orders of magnitude short of what we calculated as needed for the aLIGO signal. Yes, the question of distance from the TGF lightning has been ignored, but Fermi with its 450 mile orbital altitude probably has been as close (or closer) to a lightning storm in 4 years as the two interferometers (2000 miles apart/2=1000 miles to the lightning) were in two weeks of LIGO data taking.  We have also ignored the shielding of the atmosphere which would attenuate the energy reaching LIGO even more.

Comment: When analyzing the  possibility of  an EM origin of GW150914 we of course first thought of ELF radiation(as this was also considered by the LIGO paper mentioned above) in the form of Q-bursts either from Schumann's resonances or other lightning related sources(as I said above TGFs are often accompanied by intense ELF radiation. But as you note there is no way to produce a waveform like the correlated one coupling the oscillating field of such low freq/energy wave to the mirrors.

Comment: I should clarify something about the aLIGO interferometers system of laser and mirrors, the latter rather than simple pendulums form with the laser beams an optical spring(akin to an spring pendulum) and because of the nature of the GW signals that were most likely  expected to be detected(binary mergers) this optical spring is designed to be most sensitive in amplitude at frequencies between 80-250 Hz. It is possible for an energetic enough impulse to generate a few oscillations in this range in an optical spring pendulum. And if you look at the graph of the correlated waveforms you can....

Comment: ...see that the exact correlation between the two sites begins just before the peak amplitude and around 100 Hz, even if the previous cycles are included as part of the putative GW signal they are compatible with noise filtered in the approximate desired frequency.

Comment: See fig.1 of the detection paper, one can observe what I comment above in the first right(superposed waveform) and third rows(residual noise with numerical relativity substracted) and specially bottom row with the chirp starting at around 0.36s

Comment: @bonif I added an addendum above.  Using your idea of the laser light making an optical spring for the mirror mass, I calculate the oscillation amplitude that an EM impulse (of an amplitude just below the magnetometer veto) would cause by radiation pressure for this 100 Hz oscillator.  It appears to come out 4-5 order of magnitudes smaller than what aLIGO saw.  A 100 times larger amplitude EM pulse might do it, but that should show up in the magnetometer.

Comment: Thanks but I'm maybe not getting across my point, the radiation we are considering here as possibly producing a force in the mirrors is in the gamma frequency, much more energetic and completely out of the range that a magnetometer can detect.

Comment: @bonif   Yes, sorry, I missed your initial point.  I have added a second addendum which I think shows that the Mev/cm2 seen by Fermi(GBM) in their maximum TGF is at least 4 orders of magnitude too small to excite the 40 kg x 100 Hz osc to the amplitude that was measured.

Comment: I know you mean well but this is complex enough to resist naive approximations whithout some background on the resonant cavity properties of the interferometer, what reasonable pulses of gamma radiation one could expect to form in the lower atmosphere, their intensities...etc, no atter how many addendums could be added.

Comment: (cont) for instance on the photon counts by Fermi that you use to estimate the energy of the TGF, that number is close to useless, those are photon detected in a very inefficient way and after traversing the gamma freq  optical depth of part of the atmosphere. Very difficult to infer from that photodetection the original flux density of the gamma flash. The only way a TGF could reach the LIGO detectors is if they originate in the lower atmosphere, with very little attenuation, the photon flux would surely be many orders biger than around a 100. Unfortunately we don't have earth detectors...

Comment: ...  on the MeV energies due to the way they work and the properties of gamma radiation, so there are no statistics.

Comment: @bonif  1) We know its a 100 Hz osc from the aLIGO waveform.  We know the mass m=40 kg.   Therefore, we know the spring constant  k of the harmonic osc $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$.  Properties of the cavity can make the osc damp faster but this only makes aLIGO less sensitive to the gamma impulse.  2) If the TGF occurs in the lower atm, it has to traverse 1000 miles of full density non-line of sight atm to get to each interferometer.  If it occurs above thunder storm (~50 miles), Fermi sees it,  but still lots of atm to the interferometers, and my flux at mirror is an over (not under!) estimate.

Comment: @bonif  I like your idea of the aLIGO event being associated with an atm phenomena, particularly since Fermi GBM saw a significant gamma signal in time coincidence with the aLIGO event.  However, as I attempted to argue in the above calculation, the event really could be a radio wave (interacting with a very possibly charged mirror) from the lightning, but not the gamma ray part of the lightning's emissions supplying impulse to the mirror..

Comment: I agree that given the condition of the charged mirrors the ELF radio wave is also an interesting kind of atmosphere related EM radiation(sferics from lightning and radio bursts from TGFs) to consider as a source of the aLIGO correlated signal. The important thing to get right is what would be the most appropriate way to produce a chirp waveform exploiting the signal recycling cavity resonances(self induced antidamping) of the interferometer rather than looking for the waveform in the EM wave that would basicallly provide the external force on the mirrors.

Comment: I have almost given up any hope that anyone LIGO related visits stack  exchange by now but if anyone does it would be nice if they commented/corrected/added...

Comment: @bonif  My naïve way of getting the aLIGO pulse shape was to have an identical shape EM pulse just move the charge mirror.  A problem is that I haven't found any correctly shaped chirp EM pulses.  Now, as you suggest, maybe the short (2-3 osc of electric field) pulse from a sferic, interacting with the charge,  gives the impulse that starts the mirror osc at 100 Hz.  A property of the active aLIGO feedback system then anti-damps (amplifies) the osc for a few wiggles before damping it ... hence producing the chirp wave form.  We need more info about the feedback.

Comment: @bonif  Clearly, aLIGO must measure the charge on their mirrors.  This could be done be putting an osc voltage on some external plates and seeing how the mirrors respond.  Likewise, the voltage could be a 1 msec square wave, and see how the mirror responds.  They have done this with a magnetic field.  LIGO is a large collaboration and they undoubtedly have rules about releasing some types of information before being vetted by the collaboration.  In some ways this is good to avoid sending outsiders (like us) off on wild goose chases.  So, maybe it is unlikely we see a LIGO insider comment here.

Comment: aLIGO has electromagnetic detectors on site. The pattern in those detectors didn't match the waveform ( and was much quieter). So this can't be the cause.

Comment: @AGML  A 10 pT amplitude x 50-100 Hz EM wave is more than enough to have pulled a 16 nC charged mirror back and forth with the observed $.5*10^{-21}$ strain amplitude as shown above.  Unfortunately, 10pT is much less than the published magnetometer (range 0-900 Hz) noise $4\frac{pT}{sqrtHz}*sqrt(350-35Hz)=71pT$.  In addition (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5160.pdf) says there is an AOR AR5000a receiver tuned to 24.5 MHz (no where near 50-100 Hz) digitized at 2 kHz for RF monitoring.  Do you have info on aLIGO having other more sensitive EM monitoring in the 50-100 Hz region?

Comment: @AGML  LIGO used magnets to adjust the position/angle of the original end mirrors.  They made careful studies of the effect of environmental B fields on these magnets and then changed the final stage mirror positioning to using an electric field for aLIGO.  I'm don't know if they anticipated the end mirrors having an electric charge.

Comment: Gary in fact a Q-burst of 60 Hz freq would coincide with the local AC lines magnetic noise making it possible for a more intense transient to go undetected by the magnetometers, wich would allow a smaller average voltage in the mirrors to get the observed strain oscillations. If the anti-damping optical spring effect induced by that strain is indeed able to produce the extra 3-4 oscillations in the chirp form before it gets damped the plausibility of a correlated waveform like the one observed by LIGO not associated to GWs but to atmospheric causes should be at the least taken into account.

Comment: @Gary Godfrey You probably have heard about https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04191 by now. If confirmed it should take care of the chirp shape concerns as there would be no GW shape at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is too hand waving, it needs geographical and timing information of thunderstorms.

To get a similar strength in the two LIGOs it would have to be in the middle, and a unique crush. Thunderstorms have time sequences, very seldom there is only one isolated  bolt in time, the way the LIGO signal is.

To get serious attention by the LIGO team one could work on a preprint with the estimates of frequencies in the region between the LIGO detectors. I am sure thunder storms are recorded in some data base and a coincidence in timing could be searched.

Comment: TGFs are associated to thunderstorms but are NOT the actual visible lightning bolt. That's why they are called "dark lightning". As TGFs are not completely understood yet (and even less known by many physicists according to my experience) I recommend reading something about how they are thought to form.

Comment: And yes my team is working on a preprint with the modelling and calculations.

Comment: About the thunderstorm recordings, yes, there is such a worlwide monitoring watch. However it is obviously not exhaustive and one feature of TGFs is that they are not associated to great thunderstorms wich are the ones mostly monitored. They are observed associated to modest thunderstorms frequently.

Answer (score 2):

If there are thousands of TGR events per day worldwide then the fact they proposed signals in the detector are rare pretty much rules them out: you'd see (on average) a handful of candidate events per day as singles in each detector and a non-trivial number per month as candidate coincidences. From the single:coincidence ratio you could infer then range over which TGRs were mimicing the expected signal (which must be on order of the distance between the detectors if this hypothesis is to be true).

Comment: Over a thousand is the estimate worldwide, yes. The time the Ligo run lasted was about 15 days(a month on and off). They got at least one signal, but there's talk (rumors) of from at least one more to seven or six weaker signals more. The fact is as long as there is not a serious modelling of the amount of thunderstorms in the area capable of producing a flash with the adequate  orientation for the two sites it is very hard to say what would be the statistics(and the big iff is whether this is actually a possibility, I've only run order of magnitude estimates).

Comment: Besides, the kind of TGFs most likely to produce a signal would be from the lower atmosphere and there's no way to really know about these since basically only those from the upper atmosphere make it through to the gamma-ray telescope detectors.

Comment: You can't have it both ways on penetration. Either the events generate radiation that penetrates many hundreds of kilometers of atmosphere (for one such even to trigger both detectors) or ones in the lower atmosphere are blocked and not seen by the satellites.

Comment: Those are two different possibilities. What I'm saying is that those that are produced higher up are the ones that Fermi telescope more easily detect. And those suspected to occurr in the lower atmosphere are hardly detected by Fermi but would be more likely capable of making it to a surface sensitive enough detector.

Comment: By the way TGFs are usually accompanied by afterglows, in the form of X rays and also ELF EM waves. Fermi detected X rays 0.4 seconds after the signal that didn't trigger the monitor but was subsequently dug up from the data, it has been published and widely talked about but pointing to a possible GRB. I have knowledge on the other hand of the detection of intense ELF radiation coincident with the GW signal.